# Is there any difference between a CGRect and an NSRect?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, cocoa-touch

Is there any difference between a `CGRect` and an `NSRect`? In particular, I'm wondering about the position of the origin. Are there any important differences I need to know about?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

They're the same.  [This link](https://web.archive.org/web/20111210052652/http://cocoadev.com/index.pl?CGRect) has more information.  Copied here for quick reference:

> `CGRect` is the CoreGraphics equivalent of `NSRect`.
>
> They are deliberately made to have the same layout in memory. As such, it is allowed to convert an `NSRect` to a `CGRect` by doing this:
>
> ```
> CGRect cgrect = *(CGRect *)&nsrect;
> ```
>
> CoreGraphics also provides a `CGRectMake()` function which works the same as `NSMakeRect()` (note the reversal of verb and object in the names) except it returns a `CGRect`.

Comment: Well, that's allowed except that it breaks strict aliasing rules in the compiler.  I'll fix that wiki page.  Use NSRectFromCGRect and NSRectToCGRect to convert.

Comment: In 64-bit, or when you compile with `NS_BUILD_32_LIKE_64`, `NSRect` is defined as `CGRect`, so you don't even need to jump through the pointer hoop.

Comment: doesn't `CGRect cgrect = (CGRect) nsrect;` do the same thing?

Comment: @XAleXOwnZX - that's what Peter's comment is about.

Comment: @CarlNorum No it's not, since not everyone is using 64-bit or compiling in `NS_BUILD_32_LIKE_64` mode.

Comment: As of today, they're simply `typedef`s of each other (`typealias`es in Swift), so they are always guaranteed to be precisely the same in all uses.

Answer (score 4):

> In particular, I'm wondering about the position of the origin.

That depends on where you got the rect and where you're using it. In general, Core Graphics and UIKit use flipped co-ordinates (origin upper-left, positive y going down), whereas AppKit uses unflipped co-ordinates (origin lower-left, positive y going up). But it is possible to flip or unflip co-ordinates from each API, and some classes, such as NSImage and NSView, make it very easy to do so.

Comment: When I read his question, first I thought perhaps he was refering to the memory layout; i.e., whether the offset ("position", in his language) of the `.origin` member (and therefore, `.size` too of course) is the same on both structs. As somebody pointed above, however, the two are guaranteed to have the same memory layout.