# Casting in Swift not working as expected

Tags: swift, casting, option-type

This is a section of my code:

```
if let newValue = change?[NSKeyValueChangeNewKey] {
    print("\(newValue)")
    faceBounds = newValue as? CGRect
    print("\(faceBounds)" + " in controller")
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(),{ () -> Void in self.updateFaceRectView()})
}
```

where "faceBounds" is a CGRect? type.

However, this is the output from the system I got:

> NSRect: {{116.24999, 337.49997}, {86.249992, 86.249992}}
>
> nil in controller

What is happening? Why isn't "faceBounds" getting the correct value?

---

**[UPDATE]**

Tried this too,

```
if let newValue = change?[NSKeyValueChangeNewKey] {
    var str: String?
    str = newValue as? String
    print("\(str)")
    // Still prints nil
}
```

Is my knowledge with using casting wrong?

And btw if anyone's wondering, *newValue* is an **AnyObject** type.

Comment: Is your `newValue` ever assigned?

Comment: newValue is printed out as above

Comment: `CGRect` and `NSRect` are equivalent. This casting work properly in Objective C. I did not test in Swift. But you can try manual create the `CGRect` object from the `NSRect`

Comment: Perhaps this can fix it: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6440172/how-to-change-nsrect-to-cgrect

Comment: Updated question, doesn't seem like a NSRect problem to me:(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, I have found a workaround "for now":

```
faceBounds = newChange.CGRectValue
```

This solves the *nil* problem, but is NOT casting at all. If anyone has a more "casting" like way, please feel free to post your answer.

Answer (score 0):

As written in the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/TypeCasting.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH22-XID_516):

> AnyObject can represent an instance of any class type.

An NSRect (and CGRect) are struct types not class types so they aren't compatible with `AnyObject`, so `newValue as? CGRect` won't work. You might try casting casting to `Any` first and then try downcasting to `CGRect`.

```
let newValue = change?[NSKeyValueChangeNewKey] as! Any
faceBounds = newValue as? CGRect
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use Foundation's `NSRectToCGRect()`:

```
if let newValue = change?[NSKeyValueChangeNewKey] {
    print("\(newValue)")
    faceBounds = NSRectToCGRect(newValue)
    print("\(faceBounds)" + " in controller")
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(),{ () -> Void in self.updateFaceRectView()})
}
```