# Non-Object Attribute in Core Data, transient properties

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa, core-data

Feel lost after reading this section: [A Non-Object Attribute](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreData/Articles/cdNSAttributes.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40001919-SW14)

According to the Basic-Approach also contained in above link, I should have 2 attributes in my custom-code when handling **"transient properties"**:

1st attribute, for the actually-wanted (un-supported) custom type => **transient attribute**

2nd attribute, for shadow-representation (concrete supported) type => **persistent attribute**

......

My reading was very enjoyable, until reached "**A Non-Object Attribute**" section, which puzzle me deeply, as quoted below:

**...When you implement the entity’s custom class, you typically add an instance variable for the attribute. ...** 
《 OK, I can follow this...make an iVar is no big deal》

**If you use an instance variable to hold an attribute, you must also implement primitive get and set accessors** 
《 OK, I know how to do primitive-accessor. why need them? because internal-optimized-storage inside MO can be efficiently used, I guess.》

```
@interface MyManagedObject : NSManagedObject
  {
￼     NSRect myBounds; // I assume this suppose to be the **transient attribute**
  }
     @property (nonatomic, assign) NSRect bounds; // I assume this is the **persistent attribute**
     @property (nonatomic, assign) NSRect primitiveBounds; // because complier forces me to implement below primitive-accessors ?
@end   

- (NSRect)primitiveBounds
{
    return myBounds; // accessing iVAR storage for **transient attribute**? I hope so
}
- (void)setPrimitiveBounds:(NSRect)aRect
    myBounds = aRect; // accessing iVAR storage for **transient attribute**? I hope so
}
```

From here down below, I have... too many ???????????? unsolved

```
- (NSRect)bounds
  {
      [self willAccessValueForKey:@"bounds"]; //KVO notice of access **persistent attribute**, I guess
      NSRect aRect = bounds;                  //will this invoke primitive-Getter ???
      [self didAccessValueForKey:@"bounds"];
      if (aRect.size.width == 0)              //bounds has not yet been unarchived, Apple explained
￼￼￼      {

          NSString *boundsAsString = [self boundsAsString]; // unarchiving pseudo method, I guess
          if (boundsAsString != nil) //if that value is not nil, transform it into the appropriate type and cache it...Apple explained.
          {
              bounds = NSRectFromString(boundsAsString); //will this invoke primitive-Setter???
          }
       }
      return bounds;
  }
```

I put my final question list here:

1, do I **STILL** need to have 2 attributes to handle NON-Object-Attribute, **transient attribute** and **persistent attribute**?

2, how can iVar "myBounds" be represented/connected with "@property bounds"? Is this "@property bounds" the modeled-property in a MOM?

3, what is the purpose of implementation of primitive-accessor here? for enforcing me write KVO (will...did...) methods pair? for transferring values (in and out) between iVar "myBounds"and "@property bounds"?

4, in this line of code

```
 bounds = NSRectFromString(boundsAsString); //will this invoke primitive-Setter???
```

is primitive-Setter called OR public/standard-Setter gets called? Why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In iOS, there are the very convenient `NSStringFromCGRect` and `CGRectFromNSString` functions. Why not just use those and store a string?

Your questions:

1. Yes, you need the 2 attributes, as explained in the documentation.
2. Yes, this is based on the managed object model. The `primitiveX` name for `x` is generated / interpreted automatically.
3. You need the primitive accessor methods here to make it KVC - which is not the case with primitives.

Comment: Mundi: Because NSRect is NOT a supported type by Core Data, which makes sense for Apple to show an example of how to use "transient properties".

Comment: Are you trying to solve an academic question or a programming problem? Don't get me wrong - both is fine - but I would like to know.

Comment: Mundi:this topic is more towards practical programming problem. I just want to know how to use "transient property", don't care (actually don't have time to research) why it works in certain fashion. But I can't get there, Apple's public documentation is too big and too shallow sometimes.

Comment: Then you should go with my string suggestion. Done it many times, works as expected. See also http://stackoverflow.com/a/2151064/427083.

Comment: Mundi:appreciate your answers!!! I still have last point remaining unclear,though, so that I added 4th question. Could you square it away? Thanks again!

Comment: Why is this important? If you are interested, set breakpoints. Plus, you would not need this line, because there is no non-object transient property, just a string property which **is** an object.