# how to programmatically add buttons in swift (OS X)

Tags: swift, macos, nsbutton, programmatically-created

I've got a view and I'd like to add a check box to it under program control (no .xib file).  Here is the code I'm trying, but I get no checkbox on the screen (it does draw everything else just fine in the view). Am I missing something?

Early in the class:

```
var rodLimitsCB : NSButton?
```

inside viewWillMoveToWindow:

```
    if showRodLimits && rodLimitsCB == nil {

        rodLimitsCB = NSButton(frame: NSRect(x: self.frame.origin.x+100, y: self.frame.origin.x+100, width: 30, height: 30))
        rodLimitsCB!.setButtonType( .SwitchButton )
        rodLimitsCB!.title = "Rod Limits"
        self.addSubview( rodLimitsCB! )
    }
```

Any pointers would be appreciated.

Comment: Did you debug your code? and checked if your code is fire or not?

Comment: Yup, the code is being called (checked with NSLog and I also set a breakpoint to verify that the appropriate parameters are being passed.

Comment: I think your issue might be setting the frame of the button. i.e its off screen. "Core Graphics and UIKit use flipped co-ordinates (origin upper-left, positive y going down), whereas AppKit uses unflipped co-ordinates (origin lower-left, positive y going up)." http://stackoverflow.com/a/2151786/1186243

Comment: Changed it to `self.view.addSubview...` and that worked. Coordinates were fine.